# Is there document available regarding processing of IFRS in AX 2009?

Tags: axapta

Is there document available regarding processing of IFRS in AX 2009?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's only [KPMG audit report](http://www.kpmg.de/bescheinigung/MicrosoftBusinessSolutions/061204_KPMG_Report_MS_DynamicsAX40_en.pdf) available on this subject, however it's for AX 4.0